# Can an allocator passed to std::basic_string have its methods virtual

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I need to support various types of allocators (static, dynamic, pooled, etc) for std::basic_string. Also I want to have just one type for all these. So having multiple types like:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, static_alloc_t>
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, dyna_alloc_t>
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, pool_alloc_t>
```

is not going to work.

Can this be done if I define a base allocator type with all methods std::basic_string need as virtual and then write multiple classes deriving from this and override these virtual methods. when I create the string object I pass the correct derived type.

Would this scheme violate the standard? I have seen places where the std library creates copies of the passed allocator. In such cases it will be calling copy constructor of my base allocator instead of the derived type.

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of [`polymorphic_allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/polymorphic_allocator)?

Comment: yes, but it should be supported by c++11. I am not sure if the polymorphic_allocator is part of c++11?

Comment: No, but you can still use the design, which is implementable in C++11.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to when you say the design? Is there a specific design that I can use here which does not violate the std requirement?

Comment: [N3916](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3916.pdf) explains the design of `polymorphic_allocator` and friends. The basic stuff is straightforward to implement. (The scoped allocator model part is tricky, but you probably don't need it.)

Comment: great, Thank you. This would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done if I define a base allocator type with all methods std::basic_string need as virtual and then write multiple classes deriving from this and override these virtual methods. when I create the string object I pass the correct derived type.

Yes... but why would you do this? If you know the type the allocator does not need to be polymorphic.

If you have situations where you don't know the type and you want to treat the allocator polymorphically, it can be done but not directly.

This is because allocators must be copyable and a polymorphic object cannot be copied through its base.

You'd have to wrap the inheritance inside a concrete container class that handles the cloning properly.

You'll also have to consider the complication that one allocator must compare equal to its copy.